# Using æ, ø and å in Python

Tags: python, file-io, encode

I want to open a file which contains both the Danish æ, ø and å letters.
When I've opened the file, I'd like to organize the words and letters in the string that I saved the output of the file to.

Unfortunately; when I try to see if either of these letters are part of the string, the output comes out as a no. Here is my program:

```
wordlist = open("_newWordList.txt", "r")
print("Opened newwordlist")

for lineNo, content in enumerate(wordlist):

    s_line = content.split(";")

    print(str(lineNo)+": Checking the content: "+str(s_line)+" on line number: "+str(lineNo))

    ok = s_line[1]

    if ok[:4] == "adj.":
        adj = adj + s_line[0]

    elif ok[:10] == "ubøj. adj.":
            adj = adj + s_line[0]

    elif ok[:4] == "adv.":
        adv = adv + s_line[0]

    elif ok[:5] == "fork.":
        fork = fork + s_line[0]

    elif ok[:8] == "præfiks.":
        præfiks = præfiks + s_line[0]

    elif ok[:5] == "præp.":
        praep = praep + s_line[0]

    elif ok[:5] == "pron.":
        pron = pron + s_line[0]

    elif ok[:5] == "prop.":
        prop = prop + s_line[0]

    elif ok[:3] == "sb.":
        sb = sb + s_line[0]

    elif ok[:7] == "sb. pl.":
        sb = sb + s_line[0]

    elif ok[:9] == "udråbsord":
        uro = uro + s_line[0]

    elif ok[:3] == "vb.":
        vb = vb + s_line[0]

    else:
        print(" ")
        print("Error; didn't read any wordclass in the word: "+str(lineNo+1)+" : "+str(content))
        print("The wordclass is: "+ok)
        totalErrors += 1
```

The letters come out as weird, unreadable symbols.

Comment: are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: But, exactly what problem you are encountering is unclear to me. Please try to provide a [mcve] and be explicit about the output you are expecting, and the output you are seeing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I’m running python 3

Comment: consider posting a sample test file of 3 or 4 lines and a program that only checks one thing. That should demonstrate the problem and it would be something we could easily run.

Comment: Also, what are `sys.getdefaultencoding()` and `sys.stdout.encoding`? What encoding does the target file have, and does it match the default encoding?

Comment: As an aside, `.startswith` is a little easier to use as you don't have to know the length of the string. E.g, `ok.startswith("adv.")`.

Comment: Until you are sure you understand how file encodings work, you can use `"ub\u00f8j. adj."`, `"pr\u00e6fixs."`, and `"udr\u00e5bsord"` to specify the strings.

Comment: @tdelaney oh rhank you

Comment: ´# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-´ in 1st line of code may also help.